# Evenly Distribute menu list items using css

Tags: css

I'd like to evenly distribute the first level (horizontal) menu of this site http://ipa.staging.nextdigital.com 
without affecting the dropdown menu style layout.

HTML:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
        <li class="active has-dropdown">
            <a class="top-bar-l-1-anchor" href="/about-us">About Us</a>
                <span class="mega-menu-next js-generated">next</span>
                <ul class="dropdown" style="width: 970px;">
                    <li class="title back js-generated">
                     ...
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="/about-us/ipa-office-locations">Office locations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="/about-us/our-senior-team">Our Senior Team</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
        <li class="has-dropdown">
        <li class="has-dropdown">
        <li class="has-dropdown">
        <li class="quicklinks has-dropdown">
    </ul>
</section>
```

I tried using display: table/table-cell approach on the first level list and worked nicely 
however it carried over the second level list.

```
ul.left {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

ul.left li.has-dropdown {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    float:none;
}
ul.left li.has-dropdown li {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Any css solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: So reset display property for 'ul ul' rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to fix the size of every LI (or A) like this:

```
ul.left li {
    width: 150px;
}
```

The above will affect the next levels, so you have 2 options available:

(1) Use ">" CSS selector instead and affect direct childs only (check the browser compatibility of this CSS selector):

```
ul.left > li {
    width: 150px;
}
```

(2) Reset the next levels' width (after the very first code above):

```
ul.left li ul li {
    width: auto;
}
```

Let me know if I'm missing something else.